# OpenAPI 3.0 - Configure @RequestBody with @Schema for Post request

Tags: java, openapi, micronaut

```
@Post("/something")
@Operation(
    Summary = "Doing something",
    requestBody = @RequestBody(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(<DEFINITION>)))
)
HttpResponse doSomething(String userId, String tenantId, Person person) {

}
```

OpenAPI 3.0 removed body and formParam from @Parameter. They moved it to @RequestBody.

In @Schema DEFINITION - properties like "ref", "implementation" can define the Person object. How do I add form params like userId and tenantId in the definition?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question, but if you want to include `userId` and `tenantId` in the Schema definition, then you can also create another class representing the exact schema and use it with `@Schema` instead of Person.

Comment: Yes. That works. Is there a way to specify post "form" parameters without creating a schema?